# JDBC show all data

Tags: java, jdbc

Where is my mistake?

I run this method in my class, but an exception did occur. Why?

```
public class d3 {

Connection con;
String dbName = "mydb";
String dbUsername = "root";
String dbPassword = "2323";
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";

public d3() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Find database successfuly");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to find and load driver");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public void connectToDB() {
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUsername, dbPassword);
        System.out.println("Connect to database succesfully");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Can not connect to database");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public void excuteSQL() {
    try {
        Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet result1 = st1.executeQuery("select * from mytable");
        while(result1.next()){
            System.out.println(result1);
        }

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        System.out.println("Can not excute sql statement");
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    d3 ddd = new d3();
    ddd.connectToDB();
    ddd.excuteSQL();
}
}
```

Output:

```
Can not excute sql statement
```

The stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2618)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1557)
    at JDBCtest.d3.excuteSQL(d3.java:40)
    at JDBCtest.d3.main(d3.java:54)
```

Comment: Please post the entire stacktrace. Add `sqle.printStackTrace();` to your catch block and then run it again.

Comment: Have you tried to execute the pure sql query at your database management system? Can you provide the stacktrace?

Comment: Please add code where you initalise your connection

Comment: @JavaDevil i put whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to give database name in your url

```
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb";
```

or you can fully qualify your table name in your each of your sql queries

```
ResultSet result1 = st1.executeQuery("select * from mydb.mytable");
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems  there is problem with the SQLConnection ... Please verify that connection is successfully established.

you havn't selected the database.

Comment: You need to add the database name in the connection url. Something like `jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDB` or whatever name you have given it. Also, it's connecting at any random port?

Comment: @Sajjad - What I asked was your connection URL didn't have any port. Surely, you must have set the port when creating it, right? You have to add it after the host as well, `jdbc:mysql://localhost:8001/myDB` for example. It will also work without it, but it'd be a good practice to connect to the DB at a dedicated port.

Comment: I don't know what is my DB number?

Comment: How can i get it's number?

Comment: If you don't specify the port, it uses the MySQL default (3306).

Answer (score 1):

Your dbUrl variable should be like this:

```
 String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
```

Answer (score 1):

You either need to include the database name in the url:

```
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/theDatabase"
```

Or you need to explicitly set the database after connecting:

```
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/", 
        username, password)) {
   con.setCatalog("theDatabase");
   // querying etc
}
```

If you already know your database, and only need to use one: just specify it in the connection URL: it is easier than calling `setCatalog()` every time.